# Remote Debugging with Docker Container in VM

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, remote-debugging

I want to debug my java application work on Docker Container from my windows host machine. Besides, the container is working on VirtualBox VM. I can remotely connect to my java project folder in VM by using Remote SSH plugin of visual studio code (VSC). However, I didn't find a way to debug the java application running in the container from VSC at my windows host machine.

I didn't try yet but there will be a solution. For example, VSC is able to connect my VM by using SSH so that after the connection, VSC could be able to debug the java application. For debugging, dockerfile of the java application should be configured for enabling remote debugging also.

Is there any exact solutions or plugins which support remote debugging from host machine (in my case windows host machine) for any type of application (in my case java application) running on remote host docker container (in my case docker container running on VM)? I asked this question for visual-studio-code.

[System overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikJMZ.png)

***EDIT:***

I solved my problem with same concept but two different ways.

1. In VSC, for debugging, there should be *launch.json* and it looks like for my case

   ```
   {
     "type": "chrome",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Chrome against VM",
     "url": "http://192.168.56.101:9000",
     "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
   }
   ```

This *9000* port is exposed by the container in the VM. This *192.168.56.101* ip address belongs to VM.

2. With configuring VirtualBox port forwarding like forward host 9000 port to VM 9000 port. Thus, we should configure the *launch.json* respect to the VM configuration like

   ```
   {
     "type": "chrome",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
     "url": "http://localhost:9000",
     "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
   }
   ```

Besides, launch.json is configured for react debugging and it may be changed for other technologies.